# Redirect to login page if not authenticated from view Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working with Django rest framework.

In one view I want Users only with specific role. That is why I have used this in my view:

```
authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

But when I try to hit it without login, it only show me "403 Forbidden" which is fine, but I also want it to redirect to the default Django REST framework login page, which is at URL

`"/api-auth/login"`

How can I redirect when a login is not authenticated?

```
django==2.0
djangorestframework==3.8.2
pyton == 3.4
```

Comment: If you redirect, you will not get the appropriate 403 http status. Are you sure that's a good idea for an api?

Comment: I don't think this is a **good idea** for a **REST API**

Comment: you should define your own permission class

Comment: but you don't handle this in backend. you should do this in your frontend, like angular or android

Comment: @HakenLid  How can i achieve it ?